# Extract information from video through HDMI

Tags: hdmi

I need to develop  a device that does the following:

- Take an HDMI input
- For each frame, extract a small region of the screen. It's a small rectangle containing numerical digits that are constantly changing.
- Use these digits in an algorithm.

Which specific devices should I use for this project?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Way too broad. What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: It depends on what devices you are allowed to use. Mind you that due to HDCP protection technology used in HDMI chips, you will not be able to purchase chips that can receive HDCP protected content, so you must limit to video output devices that don't use protection.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a video frame grabber.  This isn't the shopping channel, so I won't recommend any particular brand*.  These can connect to a PC by USB (preferably USB 3.0).

Feed the video into the frame grabber, grab frames, chop out the bits you want, then use your favorite image processing library to recognize the digits.

**But if you get stuck, look up Epiphan.*

Comment: Why bother to be coy? Just say "I'm going to recommend Epiphan even though the site rules discourage product recommendations."